# Node lags behind 100 blocks, states are finished syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I run my geth node with the following command:

```
./geth --cache 8192 --syncmode full
```

It has been syncing for a long time, and it looks like it has finished syncing:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 7070318,
  highestBlock: 7070420,
  knownStates: 243826689,
  pulledStates: 243826689,
  startingBlock: 7070265
}
```

As you can see the node lags behind about 100 blocks. An explanation for this seems to be that the states have not yet finished syncing. In my case however all states are pulled. So why is it still constantly lagging behind? If it is still syncing something, is there a command which tells me the progress?

Comment: If your computer's setup is inadequate the sync will never complete - the time it catches up to the current block the blockchain has already moved on to new blocks and the cycle continues.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`eth.syncing`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsyncing)  definition, it has not finished syncing yet, if it were synced up it would return  *false*, and blockNumber for this node would be same as network. Also, all the states are not pulled up, it does not show the total number of states, it just shows that all the known states are pulled.

Comment: How can I find out the total number of states?